# How to get correctly the semaphore from shared memory

Tags: c, semaphore, shared-memory

I have a library that write in an array stored in shared memory. Now, I want to synchronize the process because there will be more process that can access and put element in this array. I'm studying semaphores but I don't understand why my process stuck without give me back any error. if I put a comment on the line of `getSemaphoreWrite()` and `releaseSemaphoreWrite()` the process works as well as without semaphore.

library:

```
void getSemaphoreWrite(){
    int semID = semget(KEY_MB_WRITE, 0,0600);
    struct sembuf sops;
    sops.sem_num = 0;
    sops.sem_op = -1;
    semop(semID,&sops,1);
}
void releaseSemaphoreWrite(){
    int semID = semget(KEY_MB_WRITE, 0,0600);
    struct sembuf sops;
    sops.sem_num = 0;
    sops.sem_op = 1;
    semop(semID,&sops,1);
} 
int addBlock(struct Block block){
    if(sizeMaster >= MAX_MASTER-1) return -1;
    getSemaphoreWrite();
    block.id = sizeMaster +1 ;
    MasterBook[sizeMaster] = block;
    ++sizeMaster;
    printf("After add a block, size: %d",sizeMaster);
    releaseSemaphoreWrite();
    return 0;
}
```

struct :

```
struct Transaction {
    int empty;
    char timestamp[30];
    int sender; /* pid user sent */
    int receiver;
    int reward;
    int money;
};

struct Block
{
    int id;
    struct Transaction tr1;
    struct Transaction tr2;
    struct Transaction reward;
};
```

in master :

```
  int semID = semget(KEY_MB_WRITE, 1, IPC_CREAT | 0600);
    if(semID == -1){
        perror("Error in sem: ");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    semctl(semID, 0, SETVAL, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected.

The `semctl(semID, 0, SETVAL, 0);` call initializes the semaphore with the value `0`. The first thing `addBlock` attempts to do is do decrement it. The whole point of the semaphore is to block the process which would make its value negative.

Try to `semctl(semID, 0, SETVAL, 1);` in master.